# How can I disable Previous button on start and Next button on the last slide in jQuery Cycle2 Malsup plugin?

Tags: jquery-cycle2

How can I disable the Previous button on the first slide and Next button on the last slide in jQuery **Cycle2** Malsup plugin?

I know this question has been answered before for the Cycle "1" plugin (and that it's posted as a [demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/after.html) on malsup's page). But how do I go about implementing it for the *Cycle 2* version? I can't seem to find a simple answer anywhere and I'm pathetically too newbie in Javascript to understand the Cycle 2 [API page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/). Could someone help me by showing me a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually done automatically if you set the `data-cycle-allow-wrap` option set to `false` in the cycle HTML.  It will add the class `disabled` to the prev/next control if it is at the beginning/end of the slideshow.  Then you just use CSS to style it so it hidden, or grayed out.  No extra Javascript needed.

Here is a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/X3kYY/

Comment: Thank you so much, Bryan. And if I want to use divs as buttons, how do I use `disabled` on them?

Comment: you just have to create the CSS for the disabled class, here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/bbernar1/X3kYY/3/